# Bootsy rails gem not showing any content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to make the [bootsy gem](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy) work with Rails 4.

Followed the requirements without installing imageMagick. I just need the editor to show but nothing is working yet.

I also got this inspecting my browser since the bootsy tags work on the form but don't show anything.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'locale' of undefined
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: you can have a look a his demo-app and compare it with yours. https://github.com/volmer/bootsy-demo

Answer (score 0):

The gem's documentation clearly states in requirements:
https://github.com/volmer/bootsy

- ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick (for MiniMagick)
- Rails 4
- Bootstrap 3 fully installed in your app.

Make sure you've installed these correctly.  Other than that, without seeing any of your code, we can only guess at solutions.  Please post code if you can.